# Open window in tab of new window

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to open a tab inside an opened window. Something like this

(it should open a new window with "google.co.uk" with a new tab "google.de"

```
newWindow = window.open('http://www.google.co.uk', '', 'width=10');
newWindowTab = newWindow.open('http://www.google.de', '_blank');
```

but this opens "newWindowTab" only in the window, where this code is.

I have also tried this, to give the window time to load, until it (should) open the new tab:

```
newWindow = window.open('http://www.google.co.uk', '', 'width=10');
setTimeout(function() {
    newWindowTab = newWindow.open('http://www.google.de', '_blank');
}, 500);
```

But then I get:

> Error: Permission denied to access property "open"

I have used firefox. I heard that it might be possible to do in Chrome, but I want to use this script in Firefox.

Comment: Pretty much the only way to get external content shown within a constrained space **in** your page is to use an `iframe`, so you could do this by managing a group of `iframe`s you show/hide via a tab bar. **However**, Google is unlikely to allow you to put an `iframe` around it.

Comment: possible it will help you [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: @The I have already seen this. But it opens only a new tab in the "main window", where the code is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It could be a good solution, but it should open an external webpage and i need to access the document inside it. This is not possible with frames, because of XSS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: @TheEquah: It's not possible *at all* (other than with CORS and such).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, unless the window being opened is from the same origin (ie the same domain).  [MDN says this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#windowObjectReference):

> The reference can be used to access properties and methods of the new
>   window provided it complies with [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) security
>   requirements.